# flash control through windows forms application does not work any more after explorer update of 26th of december 2015

Tags: forms, flash, axshockwaveflash

We have an windows form application that shows flash content.
Until saterday 26th of december 2015 this worked perfectly.

now I get:
A first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in AxShockwaveFlashObjects.dll
Additional information: The data necessary to complete this operation is not yet available. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000000A)

When I try to ask the TotalFrames from the control after loading.
Did anybody experienced the same?

Windows Forms Code (visual studio 2015):

Private WithEvents FlashControl As AxShockwaveFlashObjects.AxShockwaveFlash = Nothing

Private Sub Form1_VisibleChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.VisibleChanged
    On Error Resume Next

```
FlashControl = New AxShockwaveFlashObjects.AxShockwaveFlash
FlashControl.Name = System.Guid.NewGuid.ToString
FlashControl.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(500, 300)
Me.Controls.Add(FlashControl)
FlashControl.CreateControl()

If FlashControl.Created Then
  FlashControl.LoadMovie(0, "C:\ProgramData\PADS\Content\nds1011_contentorganizer\General-testfiles\studenthealthpack.swf")
  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
  Dim GetTotalFrames As Long = 0
  If FlashControl.TotalFrames <> 0 Then
    GetTotalFrames = FlashControl.TotalFrames
  Else
    GetTotalFrames = 0
  End If
  FlashControl.Play()
End If
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

**Found this at another website:**

> First, you will go to `Project>>Properties>>Linker>>System`, in the
>   field "SubSystem" you choose "Windows (/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS)", click
>   Apply. Then go to `Project>>Properties>>Linker>>Advanced`, in the field
>   "entry point", input value "Main" and Apply, finally click OK. After,
>   you go go file code of form you created(ex: MyForm.cpp) and input code
>   below to this file
>
> ```
> using namespace System;
>
> using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
>
> [STAThreadAttribute]
>
> void Main(array<String^>^ args)
>
> {
>
> Application::EnableVisualStyles();
> Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
> Project1::MyForm form; Application::Run(%form);
>
> }
> ```
>
> Save and exit visual studio, and then open it again, UI Form will
>   work.

Original link: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/59825/the-data-necessary-to-complete-this-operation-is-n.html